# How to delete / edit posts as staff or superuser?

Tags: django, superuser

I am fairly new to Django and right now not very familiar with the concept of Django. I created a user board (from simpleisbetterthancomplex.com) and would like to implement a Moderation with a "is_staff" user.

For now, only the user which created a post / comment is able to edit the post. As a is_staff user, I also want be able to edit ALL posts / comments.

This is the edit button:

```
        {{ post.message }}
        {% if post.created_by == user %}
          <div class="mt-3">
            <a href="{% url 'edit_post' post.topic.board.pk post.topic.pk post.pk %}"
               class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
               role="button">Edit</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
```

I thought I could so something like:

```
        {{ post.message }}
        {% if user.is_staff %}
          <div class="mt-3">
            <a href="{% url 'edit_post' post.topic.board.pk post.topic.pk post.pk %}"
               class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
               role="button">Edit</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Although I reach the correct hyperlink to edit the post, I receive a "Page not found" error.

What could be an approach to implement some Moderation to my forum?

Answer (score 1):

<s>It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code. It seems both code samples should display the same button.</s>

Please note that in this situation you should likely use a single button and tag, by changing the if to a slightly more complicated `{% if user.is_staff or post.created_by == user %}`. This should have the added effect of eliminating all possible discrepancies between the two buttons.

---

If you just want the ability to edit/delete posts, then the simplest way would likely be to use the built-in django admin panel. If you used `django startproject`, then your app already has one! Try going to `localhost:8000/admin` (by default) to check it out.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/

---

**EDIT:** I think I can see the problem. You filter your queryset in PostUpdateView by `(created_by=self.request.user)`. This filter works differently when dealing with a different user, such as the moderator. Try changing the view to reflect this.

Comment: Hey, the second button appears if I am online with my staff user. The second one was just for testing purposes. The hyperlink to the edit post just doesnt work

Comment: I see, you're right! Check the post edit for details

Comment: Okay, got it. So.. return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user) should be something like return queryset.filter(created_by=username_which_created_the_post), because the other one is returning the currently user logged in, right?

Comment: That's right! You were simply returning the wrong user :)

Comment: The call, queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user), is being used to ensure that only the user that created the post can update it. By removing this, any user will be allowed to update the post. You really need to keep that functionality and add access to a staff user separately.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the URL returned by edit_post. This view only allows access to owners of the post, so no one else can access this view.

You would need to add to the view to allow users with is_staff = True to also access this view.

The problem is with the queryset definition filtering out models not created by the user. But you want to keep this, so that other users don't have access.

You could remove the get_queryset call and adjust the dispatch method to only allow the owner or staff members to view. But I suggest keeping this intact and add a new moderator update view and use django braces to sort out the permissions. Something like;

```
from braces.views import StaffuserRequiredMixin


class ModeratorUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, 
                          StaffuserRequiredMixin,
                          UpdateView):
    ## Update Code here ##
```

Comment: If this view only allows access to owners of the post, then no one else can access this view. - I guess thats the point here. Will post the view - thank you so much to help me understand Django.

Answer (score 0):

The view of my board:

```
class BoardListView(ListView):
    model = Board
    context_object_name = 'boards'
    template_name = 'home.html'


class TopicListView(ListView):
    model = Topic
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    template_name = 'topics.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['board'] = self.board
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        queryset = self.board.topics.order_by('-last_updated').annotate(replies=Count('posts') - 1)
        return queryset


@login_required
def new_topic(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewTopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            topic = form.save(commit=False)
            topic.board = board
            topic.starter = request.user  # <- here
            topic.save()
            Post.objects.create(
                message=form.cleaned_data.get('message'),
                topic=topic,
                created_by=request.user  # <- and here
            )
            return redirect('topic_posts', pk=pk, topic_pk=topic.pk)  # TODO: redirect to the created topic page
    else:
        form = NewTopicForm()
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'board': board, 'form': form})


def topic_posts(request, pk, topic_pk):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=pk, pk=topic_pk)
    topic.views += 1
    topic.save()
    return render(request, 'topic_posts.html', {'topic': topic})


@login_required
def reply_topic(request, pk, topic_pk):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=pk, pk=topic_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.topic = topic
            post.created_by = request.user
            post.save()

            topic.last_updated = timezone.now()
            topic.save()

            topic_url = reverse('topic_posts', kwargs={'pk': pk, 'topic_pk': topic_pk})
            topic_post_url = '{url}?page={page}#{id}'.format(
                url=topic_url,
                id=post.pk,
                page=topic.get_page_count()
            )

            return redirect(topic_post_url)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'reply_topic.html', {'topic': topic, 'form': form})


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ('message', )
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_pk'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.updated_by = self.request.user
        post.updated_at = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('topic_posts', pk=post.topic.board.pk, topic_pk=post.topic.pk)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'topic_posts.html'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        session_key = 'viewed_topic_{}'.format(self.topic.pk)
        if not self.request.session.get(session_key, False):
            self.topic.views += 1
            self.topic.save()
            self.request.session[session_key] = True

        kwargs['topic'] = self.topic
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board__pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'), pk=self.kwargs.get('topic_pk'))
        queryset = self.topic.posts.order_by('created_at')
        return queryset
```

And the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import Truncator
import math


class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_posts_count(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).count()

    def get_last_post(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(topic__board=self).order_by('-created_at').first()


class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  # <- here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject

    def get_page_count(self):
        count = self.posts.count()
        pages = count / 20
        return math.ceil(pages)

    def has_many_pages(self, count=None):
        if count is None:
            count = self.get_page_count()
        return count > 6

    def get_page_range(self):
        count = self.get_page_count()
        if self.has_many_pages(count):
            return range(1, 5)
        return range(1, count + 1)

    def get_last_ten_posts(self):
        return self.posts.order_by('-created_at')[:10]


class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        truncated_message = Truncator(self.message)
        return truncated_message.chars(30)
```